# How do I use the flashlight?

Tags: firewatch

I found a flashlight in Supply Cache 303. How do I use the flashlight?

[image: Flashlight in a supply cache]

Comment: was this... something you struggled with, and needed to make into a Q/A?

Comment: The game didn't explain how to use the flashlight. The dialogue when I picked it up made me think I would only be able to use it at night. It took me 30 minutes or so before I accidentally figured out how to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To toggle the flashlight on or off press <kbd>F</kbd> on a keyboard or click the Right Stick on a controller.

[image: Keyboard controls]

[image: Gamepad controls]